# First user input attempt not working (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to get the user input and when I put a value for the first attempt it will give me the question again "Enter the Expression (% to break):" although if the first attempt is blank it will give the correct error message "Expression cannot be blank".
So what I need is how to get the first attempt to work.

THANKS THIS HAS BEEN SOLVED!! I REALLY APPRECIATE IT!

```
package PrefixCalc;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrefixCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Expressions calc;
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the Expression(% to break): ");
        String line = console.nextLine();
        while (line.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Expression cannot be empty!");
            System.out.print("Enter the Expression(% to break): ");
            line = console.nextLine();
        }
        while (!line.isEmpty()) {
            if (line.equals("%")) {
                break;
            } else {

                if (args.length > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Processing string " + args[0]);
                    calc = new Expressions(new Scanner(args[0]));
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Enter the Expression(% to break): ");
                    calc = new Expressions(new Scanner(console.nextLine()));   //System.in
                }

                System.out.println("\nInput as prefix expression:");
                calc.showPreFix();
                System.out.println("Result: " + calc.evaluate());
                System.out.println("infix expression:");
                calc.showInFix();
                System.out.println("...................................................");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop, you are not using the input you received from the console in your if statements, you are using `args`, the input into the main method, which is not the value the user inputted after being prompted with `"Enter the Expression(% to break): "`.

The problem is right here:

```
            if (args.length > 0) {  <--- args instead of line
                System.out.println("Processing string " + args[0]);
                calc = new Expressions(new Scanner(args[0]));
            } else {
                System.out.print("Enter the Expression(% to break): ");
                calc = new Expressions(new Scanner(console.nextLine()));   //System.in
            }
```

`args.length` is `0` because, presumably, you did not run this method with any commands. Because `args` is empty, you are going into the else statement and printing out the `"Enter the Expression(% to break): "` prompt a second time.

Just use the `line` variable in the `if-statment` and it should work fine. Like this:

```
            if (line.length > 0) {
                System.out.println("Processing string " + args[0]);
                calc = new Expressions(new Scanner(args[0]));
            } else {
                System.out.print("Enter the Expression(% to break): ");
                calc = new Expressions(new Scanner(console.nextLine()));   //System.in
            }
```

Also, you should probably reassign `line` to the new value you are getting after the second prompt. You need to do something with it to avoid an infinite loop. See @Kevin Bowersox's answer for an elegant solution to that problem.

Comment: At some point `line` needs to be reassigned with the new value entered or else the `while` loop will never exit.

Comment: Agreed and added. I accidentally didn't scroll all the way down so I thought some of the while loop was not posted, but you're right. The OP will never exit the while loop as written. I don't think that is the cause of the original problem posted though

Comment: Agreed, not the cause of the original problem. +1

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why the `Expressions` constructor accepts an argument of type `Scanner`

Comment: Yeah, that's a little odd. There is probably room for enhancement there. Expressions isn't a built in java class is it? I don't see it in the imports and I didn't find anything when I googled for it (I don't ever pretend to know all the different Java classes there are)

Answer (score 1):

The code is creating an infinite loop.  The following `while loop` executes while `line` is not empty, however it will never be empty since the `String line` is never modified.  At some point `line` needs to be assigned the value entered by the user, so that it can break appropriately if a `%` is entered. Also I'm not sure why the code uses the arguments passed into the main method, instead it should be using `line`.

```
  //if line contains anything other than `%` it causes an infinite loop
  while (!line.isEmpty()) {
            if (line.equals("%")) {
                break;
            } else {

                if (args.length > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Processing string " + args[0]);
                    calc = new Expressions(new Scanner(args[0]));
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Enter the Expression(% to break): ");
                    calc = new Expressions(new Scanner(console.nextLine()));   //System.in
                }

                System.out.println("\nInput as prefix expression:");
                calc.showPreFix();
                System.out.println("Result: " + calc.evaluate());
                System.out.println("infix expression:");
                calc.showInFix();
                System.out.println("...................................................");
            }
        }
```

**FIX**

```
  while (!line.isEmpty()) {
            if (line.equals("%")) {
                break;
            } 
                calc = new Expressions(new Scanner(line));
                System.out.println("\nInput as prefix expression:");
                calc.showPreFix();
                System.out.println("Result: " + calc.evaluate());
                System.out.println("infix expression:");
                calc.showInFix();
                System.out.println("...................................................");
                System.out.print("Enter the Expression(% to break): ");
                line = console.nextLine();

        }
```